# Copy and Transpose Paste many records excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried everything and this doesn't seem to work. I have a spreadsheet with data on the first column vertically that I need transposed horizontally.[image: OriginalData up to 5000 records]

[image: And I'd like it to be arranged like this:]

What would be the fastest way to get this done?

EDIT: I was able to temporarily resolve my issue with the following macro:

```
Sub CopyTranspose()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow, x, y As Long

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
y = 3

For x = 2 To LastRow Step 48
    Range(Cells(x, 4), Cells(x + 47, 2)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    y = y + 1
Next x
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The above solution assumes that all days are uniform with 48 time intervals. But now I need a more dynamic Macro: one that will find the date e.g. 1/1/17 and match it with the interval time and total. So, that is to say, days that have less than 48 intervals (e.g. daylight savings time which have an hour missing) will simply return a 0 (or null) value at the missing 2am - 3am interval.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: Hi @Tim-Williams. A pivot table will not provide the solution we need. A macro is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
 dim r as range
 set r = your range here
 r.copy
 range(your destination).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Whereas a macro is the way to go, it needs a bit more tweaking so that it can match times and dates into the grid.